# Need to Release a com_ptr_t before reassigning with CreateInstance?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, createinstance

In a C++ class with _com_ptr_t members, will memory leak if CreateInstance() is repeatedly used on the same pointer to get fresh instances of COM objects, without first performing a Release()?  It's well documented that ref count is decremented when one of these smart pointers goes out of scope, and that it is not when the encapsulated pointer is Detach()ed. MSDN doesn't seem to mention the implications of ref counting when repeating CreateInstance().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No leak will occur since `_com_ptr_t` calls `Release()` at the beginning of `CreateInstance()` which you can easily verify yourself by reading `_com_ptr_t` implementation.

Comment: Thanks sharptooth.  I had trouble following _com_ptr_t::CreateInstance to the source in the Visual Studio IDE, presumably because it is a template.  Referencing MSDN identified comip.h as the source file of interest.  It took me a minute to realize the alternate prototypes call the main version (that takes a CLSID as the first argument), which clearly calls _Release() before doing anything else.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

CreateInstance() calls 
       _Release() before calling the CoCreateInstance(). Please see the implementation inside.